# 2 conditions for creating a boolean vector

Tags: r, if-statement, operators, boolean

I have 2 vectors and single a number.

```
a <- rnorm(40,10,4)
d <- rep(0,length(a)
filling_limit <- 8
```

Now, I want a 40*1 boolean vector (`has.room`) giving me info if the 2 conditions are satisfied:

```
has.room  <- a > 0 && d < filling_limit
```

instead of returning a vector with 40 times `TRUE` I get just a single `TRUE`.
What's the reason for this? If you are wondering about the zero vector: This thing is part of a loop and `d` will change within time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
has.room  <- a > 0 & d < filling_limit
```

From the help page for logical operators:
`&` and `&&` indicate logical AND and `|` and `||` indicate logical OR. **The shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as arithmetic operators. The longer form evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each vector.** Evaluation proceeds only until the result is determined.

Comment: +1 for the explanation. You might indicate that the help page you quote can be access via `?"&&"` or `?Logic` for example.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
has.room  <- a > 0 & d < filling_limit
```

Comment: I would also suggest the OP check out `?"&"`